# Download issue in MVC Webgrid using Base64 String

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to implement the download functionality in MVC web grid. Here is demo code.

**Model**

```
 public class Student
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }

        public string ByteArray { get; set; }

        public List<Student> StudentList { get; set; }

    }
```

**View**

```
 @model Fileuploaddemo.Models.Student

   @{ var grid = new WebGrid(Model.StudentList);}

    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)

    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address)

  @grid.GetHtml(            
                  htmlAttributes: new
                  {
                      id = "gridT1",
                      @calss = ""
                  },
    tableStyle: "webgrid-table",
    headerStyle: "webgrid-header",           
    columns: grid.Columns(
    grid.Column(columnName: "Name", header: "Name"),
    grid.Column(columnName: "Address", header: "Address") ))
```

**Controller**

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Student obj = new Student();
            obj.StudentList = new List<Student>();
            return View(obj);

        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(Student obj, HttpPostedFileBase file1)
        {
            if (file1 != null)
            {
                MemoryStream target = new MemoryStream();
                file1.InputStream.CopyTo(target);
                byte[] data = target.ToArray();
                obj.ByteArray = Convert.ToBase64String(data);
            }

            obj.StudentList = new List<Student>();
            obj.StudentList.Add(obj);
            return View(obj);

        }
```

Here in this code, I am trying to display the Student details in the MVC Web grid along with file download option.

But Here, I am not getting how to download the file, which is in base64string format.

Please assist me in resolving the issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an extra colum to your `WebGrid` which will have a link called "Download".This link needs to call the download action in the controller and pass through the base64 property of the clicked student.Below is a complete working example, hope it helps you:

**Controller:**

```
public class StudentController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Student obj = new Student();
        byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("F:\\test.txt");
        string ba = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);

        var s1 = new Student { Name = "Student1", Address = "Address1", ByteArray = ba };
        var s2 = new Student { Name = "Student2", Address = "Address2", ByteArray = ba };
        var s3 = new Student { Name = "Student3", Address = "Address3", ByteArray = ba };

        obj.StudentList = new List<Student>() { s1, s2, s3 };
        return View(obj);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public FileResult DownloadAction(string file)
    {
        byte[] fileBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(file);
        string fileName = "test.txt";
        return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
@model Fileuploaddemo.Models.Student

@{ var grid = new WebGrid(Model.StudentList);}

@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)

@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address)


@grid.GetHtml(
                  htmlAttributes: new
                  {
                      id = "gridT1",
                      @calss = ""
                  },
    tableStyle: "webgrid-table",
    headerStyle: "webgrid-header",
    columns: grid.Columns(
    grid.Column(columnName: "Name", header: "Name"),
    grid.Column(columnName: "Address", header: "Address"),
    grid.Column("Download", "Download", format: @<text>
        @Html.ActionLink("Download", "DownloadAction", "Student", new { file = item.ByteArray },null)
    </text>)
    ))
```

Comment: I have tried this but unable to pass the file as routing value in the actionlink because it is stored in Base64string format.

Comment: Why not?I'm passing it through in the example above and it works just fine.Anyway, you can always pass through the ID of the record to the controller and in the controller use the ID to look up the base64 string and do the download, it's really simple.Just add an ID property to the student class and change the ActionLink to be Html.ActionLink("Download", "DownloadAction", "Student", new { id = ID },null)